# determine the point that 2 chart reach each other in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to determine the point that 2 charts reach each other in matlab and insert an annotation there that show the x and y axis of the point.  At th emoment I have the below code and chart:

```
G=sort(G);
plot(G,'g')
grid
hold on
I=sort(I,'descend');
plot(I,'r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of doing it is solving the equation, if you have an equation.

Else, after sorting your data:

`idx=find(G>I,1)`

Gives you the index were green is bigger than red, so thats about where they cross. Once you know the point, just use [annotation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html), for example